# `npm i` does NOT generate package-lock.json and node_modules inside modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

I have the following source tree:

```
/project/
  |- package.json
  |- package-lock.json
  |- tsconfig.json
  |- node_modules
  |- src/
      |- moduleA
          |- package.json
          |- tsconfig.json
          |- index.ts
          |- classA.ts
      |- moduleB
          |- package.json
          |- tsconfig.json
          |- classB.ts
```

`moduleA` `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Web API Core module",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json && npm run rollup",
    "build:watch": "nodemon -e ts --exec \"npm run build\" --ignore build/** --ignore tests/**",
    "rollup": "rollup -c"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^3.2.4",
    "express": "^4.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.4",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^18.6.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "rollup": "^2.77.2",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^4.2.2",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "main": "index.js",
  "types": "build/src/index.d.ts",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.4.0"
  }
}
```

`ROOT` `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "exports": "./bin/www.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "src/moduleA",
    "src/moduleB"
  ]
}
```

I run `npm i` inside each of the module's folder and expect `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` generated but it isn't. There is no `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder inside `moduleA` and `moduleB`.

To confirm, I remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` at the `ROOT` of the source tree and run `npm i` inside one of the modules, the artefacts are generated in the `ROOT` of the source tree.

Is this the right expected behaviour?

```
$ npm config ls -l|grep package-lock
npm WARN config This command does not support workspaces.
format-package-lock = true 
package-lock = true 
package-lock-only = false
```

npm version: 8.15.0

node version: 18.4.0

Running `rm -rf node-modules && npm i` and `npm install --package-lock` does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Is there a `package.json` in your current working directory?

Comment: Yes, of course. I have updated my question. `package-lock.json` is missing from modules folder.

Comment: Where is the `package.json`?

Comment: What's the content of `package.json`? Why is there a `package-lock.json`? Where do you run `npm i`?

Comment: I run `npm i` in `src/moduleA` folder and expect `package-lock.json` generated in the module folder.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What's the content of `project/src/moduleA/package.json`? What output do you get?

Comment: Isn't that in my post?

Comment: Do you get an error, when you run `npm i`? Does it create `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` in the root folder of the project?

Comment: It looks like `project/src/moduleA/package.json` can't be found. Maybe a typo?

Comment: If it is not found there will be an error shown on the shell, duh!!!!

Comment: No, `npm i` will traverse upwards in the filesystem until it finds a `package.json` in the project root.

Comment: No, the files are there inside the modules

Comment: What's the content of `project/package.json`?

Comment: You have workspaces. This is the expected behavior. With a [mcve] I could answer your question one hour ago and save us some time.

Comment: I see. Is there any documentation/reference on this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course. It's documented with the other features of npm.

Comment: Can you please share the URL specifically for this? Thanks.